# how to load or draw a bitmap on the propertysheet horizontal footer (area behind navigation buttons)?

Tags: mfc

I am bit confused how to draw or load a bitmap on the propertysheet horizontal footer(horizontal seperator at the bottom) I.e. the area behind the navigation buttons(Next,Back,Cancel buttons).Is it possible to load or draw a bitmap on the footer of the sheet.

[image]

If possible can anyone please let me know how to draw or load bitmap on the footer(which is pointed out in red color that entire area has to be loaded with a bitmap) .

Answer (score 0):

if you search on google for "mfc c++ draw a bitmap in a dialog background" you will see this article as the first result http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18967/Bitmap-Backgrounds-For-Dialog-Boxes and it explains very well on how to draw a bitmap as a dialog background.

the only difference is that when you call the [CDC::BitBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/fcbk8779.aspx) you just pass the x and y values that match with the area you want